# What should I use java input function in this case?

Tags: java

I want to make a string array.
For example,
If I enter the `12 34 56 78`,
then string `array[0]` is "12", `array[1]` is "34", `array[2]` is "56" etc.
I tried to use scanner or string reader class but I don't know how to detect blank.

Comment: `String#split` is your friend.

Comment: -1 this shows a huge lack of basic research!

Comment: Sorry, I retrieve many times about this problem but I don't find about split.

Comment: Show the code you have tried. Otherwise, risk having the question closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String a = "12 12 34 5435452";
String[] b = a.split(" ");
```

Comment: For more help, documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public class abc {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String a = "12 12 34 5435452";
        String[] b = a.split(" ");

        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(b[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It's the same code of @Sara Seppola, just already done...